# C - Pointer to dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I encountered a problem with pointers. I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Concert {
    char* nameOfBand;
    char* location;} concert;
}
```

and I would like to have a dynamic array of structs.

So I need to create a variable for storing an array of structs, and then add structs to it. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
//pointer to array   
concert** concertArray = (concert**) malloc(sizeof(concert)*5);

//new concert
concert newConcert;
newConcert.nameOfBand = "name1";
newConcert.location = "location1";

//adding item to array
*((*concertArray)+0) = newConcert;
```

But it fails while compiling.

Comment: Can you post the compiler error?

Comment: Why `concertArray` is `**`? This is wrong. Or the allocation is wrong.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: As is usually the problem here, you are NOT copying `newConcert`. You are just putting the pointerr to a local (automatic) variable in the array, and that pointer goes out-of-scope (no longer exists) when you return form the function. Use `malloc` to allocate a new concert, then fill in the data (and malloc for EACH string too!!).

Comment: Your code program __compiles__ fine. Whether it __runs__ correctly is another story. Please [edit] your question and make clear what __exactly__ does not work.

Comment: @apalomer it just crashes. CLion doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @FaustasButkus So it crashes but in your question it fails while you compile it, please [edit] your question and correct it.

Comment: @FaustasButkus that's because you're trying to access `concertArray[0]` when it doesn't point to a valid memory location.

Comment: Just do not try to learn C by Trial&Error, this is know to cause depressions. Start by reading a book.

Comment: "Fails while compiling" - a compiler is **required** to produce an error message. Such an error message is of **great importance** in a question about code that fails to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is usually the problem here, you are NOT copying `newConcert`. You are just putting the pointerr to a local (automatic) variable in the array, and that pointer goes out-of-scope (no longer exists) when you return form the function. Use `malloc` to allocate a new concert, then fill in the data (and malloc for EACH string too!!). The following does this and is a more complete example:

```
typedef struct Concert {
    char* nameOfBand;
    char* location;
} concert;

concert** concertArray;
int nConcerts;

int main()
{
    int i;
    concertArray = malloc(sizeof(concert *)*5); // allocate array
    addConcert("name1", "location1");           // add element

    // print elements
    for (i=0; i<nConcerts; i++)
        printf("Name: %s, location: %s\n", concertArray[i]->nameOfBand, concertArray[i]->location);

    // free concerts
    for (i=0; i<nConcerts; i++) {
        free(concertArray[i]->nameOfBand);
        free(concertArray[i]->location);
        free(concertArray[i]);
    }
    free(concertArray);
    return 0;
}
void addConcert(char *name, char *location)
{
    concert *newConcert = malloc(sizeof(concert));
    newConcert->nameOfBand = malloc(strlen(name)+1); strcpy(newConcert->nameOfBand, name);
    newConcert->location = malloc(strlen(location)+1);  strcpy(newConcert->location, location);

    concertArray[nConcerts++] = newConcert;
}
```

Comment: Do this line `newConcert->nameOfBand = malloc(strlen(name)+1);` is correct? I think it should be `(*newConcert)->nameOfBand = malloc(strlen(name)+1);`?

Comment: I tried your code. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
concert** concertArray = (concert**) malloc(sizeof(concert)*5);
```

does not make sense.

Instead try the following

```
//pointer to array   
concert *concertArray = malloc( sizeof( concert[5] ) );

//new concert
concert newConcert;
newConcert.nameOfBand = "name1";
newConcert.location = "location1";

//adding item to array
concertArray[0] = newConcert;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Concert 
{
    char* nameOfBand;
    char* location;

} concert;

int main(void) 
{
    //pointer to array   
    concert *concertArray = malloc( sizeof( concert[5] ) );

    //new concert
    concert newConcert;
    newConcert.nameOfBand = "name1";
    newConcert.location = "location1";

    //adding item to array
    concertArray[0] = newConcert;

    printf( "Name: %s, Location: %s\n", 
        concertArray[0].nameOfBand, concertArray[0].location );

    free( concertArray );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Name: name1, Location: location1
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code....

```
*((*concertArray)+0) = newConcert;
```

is the same as....

```
*concertArray[0] = newConcert;
```

Whilst that makes them the same type, your code won't work because `concertArray[0]` is an undefined pointer and you're dereferencing it.

You need to allocate memory for each element of `concertArray` and then you can make use of the `concert` you've created like in the below example.

```
concertArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(concert));
concertArray[0]->nameOfBand = "name1";
concertArray[0]->location = "location1";
```

Comment: "*`*((*concertArray)+0) = newConcert;` is the same as....*" `(*concertArray)[0] = newConcert;`

Comment: Assuming "*`concert** concertArray`*", doing  `concertArray[0]` would fail without correct allocation to `concertArray`, which the OP's is not.

Comment: @alk it's also the same as `**concertArray` too, but at the end of the day, the problem is the OP is dereferencing a pointer that isn't initialised

Comment: Fair enough, I took thr `0` as an `N`, with `N>=0`.